# Java Selenium web Element Variable vs Web Element Array

Tags: java, selenium, arraylist

could someone tell me why if I run the following code I don´t get any error:

```
 private WebElement userNameTxt ;
 public RegisterPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        userNameTxt = By.id("user_name");
 }
 public void registerElement() {
  WebElement user = driver.findElement(userNameTxt);
}
```

but if I run this code I get Java.nullpointerException?

```
 private ArrayList<WebElement> registerElements;
 private WebElement userNameTxt ;
 public RegisterPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        ArrayList <WebElement>registerElements = new ArrayList();
        userNameTxt = By.id("user_name");
 }
 public void registerElement() {
  registerElements.add(0, driver.findElement(userNameTxt))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You’re doing name shadowing in your constructor, so it’s not actually assigning a value to the private class variable as you expect.

Remove the type declaration so you just have `this.registerElements = new ArrayList()`